# IntelliJ bundled Ant location

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, ant, macos-sierra, java-6

I'm trying to work on an old Java 6 project but IntelliJ says that I'm using a bundled Ant (1.10.5) which isn't compatible with Java 6 so I can't compile the project using Ant. Is there a way to find where the bundled ant jar file is located within the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the bundled Ant version, instead you can supply your own Ant installation path in IntelliJ IDEA [build file properties dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/defining-ant-execution-options.html).

Bundled Ant can be found in `IDE_HOME/lib/ant` directory (`/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant` on macOS).

Comment: What are the negative consequences of changing the bundled Ant version?

Comment: @DarrelHolt IDE patch updates will not work, on Mac digital signature will be violated and OS security will block IDE connections, you will have to explicitly allow the app to run and whitelist it in the firewall.

Comment: It bothers me that this, despite giving good information, does not answer what the OP asked and still it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @RenatoBack it solves the original problem. If it doesn't solve your problem, please submit a new question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder don't take it bad, it might have solved the problem, however it does not answer the question which is "...Is there a way to find where the bundled ant jar file is located within the project?", which the OP himself answered on his own.

Comment: @RenatoBack Bundled Ant jar is not located within the project, replacing this jar on macOS will violate application digital signature and cause various issues. The answer provided solves the problem using the proper way instead of using the hacky workarounds, therefore it was accepted by the OP. If your use case requires replacing IDE jar files, let us know why you need it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder you're still missing the point. The question asks where is the jar located at. I never said I want to replace it, nor that I have a question myself. What I did say is that your's is not a direct/correct answer to what the OP explicitly asked. Cheers.

Comment: @RenatoBack direct answer is not always the correct one and may not actually solve the problem. I've been doing support for 20 years and I have some experience how to approach the problems and how to solve them in a correct way.

Comment: @CrazyCoder congrats, gramps. Check the [Help Center - Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) post and recap. You got the **Answer the question** section by providing a viable alternative, however people might just want to find out where the lib is at, not necessarily change it. For that, I still believe this answer is incomplete. Editing it to include such information would get a vote up, for sure. That's all from my side.

Answer (score 4):

> In IntelliJ 2019.2 go to Ant Tool Window > Build File Properties > Execution > Use
>   Custom Ant to specify the Ant version downloaded

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that the bundled Ant is located in `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant`.

You can also add other versions of ant to the `lib` directory after downloading them. They should be identified by IntelliJ for other projects after adding it in the Ant Build Properties if you wish to change the Ant version.

For example, adding Ant 1.9.4: `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ant_1.9.4`.